# Gitlab Branch/Tag comparision from Lower Version to updated version

Tags: compare, gitlab, diff

I created two tags and compared them by keeping Tag1 as `Source` and Tag2 as `Target`, then the output came as *There isn't anything to compare.
You'll need to use different branch names to get a valid comparison.*

If I interchanged the tags i.e., Tag2 as `Source` and Tag1 as `Target`, then the `diff` are shown properly. Why the `diff` is not shown when Updated version is in `Target`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been seen in [gitlab-ce issue 37889](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37889), but that might not be a bug.

> The per-project compare page allows the input of two SHA1, but clicking on the compare button returns this message:

```
There isn't anything to compare.
You'll need to use different branch names to get a valid comparison.
```

> However, comparing from an old commit on master to `master` itself gives the expected result (all the commits from the old commit to the HEAD of `master` are shown), so it seems that the functionality is there.

This is still visible with the latest 10.x GitLab version.

---

The comment of [issue 25162](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25162) illustrates the issue:

> Comparing [e1bf40e2](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/e1bf40e293409d974a8013685ec544c0f633ef16) to [3d0074a6](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/3d0074a6edc22eb6840bad639c8f4fde6be89293) works as expected. However, reverse the order and "There isn't anything to compare.".
>
> This one is okay:
>   [e1bf40e2...3d0074a6](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/compare/e1bf40e2...3d0074a6)
>
> This one is not okay:
>   [3d0074a6...e1bf40e2](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/compare/3d0074a6...e1bf40e2)

But:

> I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I also don't know what the intent for the compare tool in GitLab is suppose to do.
>
> I assume GitLab is diffing 2 commits with 3 dots.  The 3 dots will tell Git to use the common ancestor for diffing.
>
> The issue is `3d0074a6...e1bf40e2` would be the same as executing `git diff $common-ancestor e1bf40e2` where `$common-ancestor` is the result of executing `git merge-base 3d0074a6 e1bf40e2` which is `e1bf40e2`
>
> So what's happening is, you are executing `git diff e1bf40e2 e1bf40e2` which is why there is no difference.
>
> I'm guessing you want to execute `git diff 3d0074a6 e1bf40e2`  without the dots, which will tell Git to diff the commits and not the common ancestor.

So check your diff URL: if you see three dots, the error message is then expected.

Comment: When I compare most earlier Tags, Say TAG0 as `source` and TAG2 as `target` then some diffs are shown. Why this happened?

Comment: @RajanaDeepak I have edited my answer to explain why this happens.